My electron exe app(used to run and react application) is not running
I'm having react-electron app, while making this app as exe file using electron-builder.
After making the exe, if i try to run the exe, blank window is opening. But if i open the the same application in localhost and then try to open the exe, the exe is opening perfectly.
My entry point is main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const createWindow = () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'SieAPIAssure',
        webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

this is my pacakage.json
{
  "name": "sieapiassure.ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "SieAPIAssure",
  "author": "Abhay Singh, Vikash Shukla, Sharath Roy",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^8.0.7",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.16.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^7.14.0",
    "@mui/x-tree-view": "^7.14.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "wait-on": "^7.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm run electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "yarn build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
  "build": {
    "npmRebuild": false,
    "appId": "com.sieapiassure.id",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "main.js"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "signingHashAlgorithms": [],
      "certificateFile": null,
      "certificateSubjectName": null
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^32.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^25.0.5"
  }
}

and app component is
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import Header from './components/header/header';
import NavBar from './components/navbar/navbar';
import Home from './components/home/home';
import Project from './components/project/project';
import CreateProject from './components/project/createproject/createproject';
import ViewProjects from './components/viewprojects/viewprojects';
import Execution from './components/execution/execution';
import Report from './components/report/report';  

function App() {    

   
    const [projectDetails, setProjectDetails] = useState({});
    

  

    
    const handleSaveProject = (details) => {
        setProjectDetails(details);
    };
    

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="app">
                <Header className="header" />
                <NavBar className="navbar" />
                <div className="main">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/' element={ <Navigate to = "/home"/>} />
                        <Route path="/home" element={
                            <Container sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: 5 }}>
                                <Home />
                            </Container>
                        } />
                        <Route path="/home/project" element={<Project projectDetails={projectDetails} />} />
                        <Route path="/home/createproject" element={
                            <CreateProject
                                open={true} 
                                onClose={() => { }}
                                onSave={handleSaveProject}
                            />
                        } />
                        <Route path="/viewprojects" element={<ViewProjects />} />
                        <Route path="/execution" element={<Execution />} />
                        <Route path="/report" element={<Report />} />
                        <Route path="#" element={<div style={{ height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'black' }}></div>} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
how to make it working

Hi, you need to tell us more. Do you get any errors when running the exe in the main process? Can you open chromium devtools and see what's wrong with the renderer process?

This question is similar to: packaging an electron App results in an empty UI. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i have used both BrowserRouter and HashRouter

In production, you should use your built HTML file instead of localhost:
app.isPackaged
  ? mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html")) // Prod
  : mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000"); // Dev

